# how can I configure log4j so that it stops showing xml escape characters

Tags: log4j

Hi In my application we are logging the xml requests to a file using patternlayout. 
The xml has a password field. but in log log4 it shows < &gt

I want it to show '<' and '>'

how can I do that?

Thanks,
Manoj

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it isn't log4j's fault, PatternLayout does not convert characters to entities. It must be happening when the XML is constructed.